# Posting data from listview of android to server in a loop using multipart

Tags: android, android-listview, multipartform-data

**I have a list of data displayed in a listview .... data is parsed from JSON and displayed here**

---

***Present Snapshot***::

[image]

---

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView name;
        ImageView flag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RestaurantNameID);
        flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        name.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
        // Capture ListView item click

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

**ListOfContacts.java**

```
public class ListOfContacts extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "rank";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);


        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();


    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListOfContacts.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7004/DescriptionSortedPrice/");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put(ListOfContacts.NAME, jsonobject.getString("Person_Name"));
                    map.put(ListOfContacts.FLAG, "http://54.218.73.244:7004/"+jsonobject.getString("Image_Name"));



                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(ListOfContacts.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**listview_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantPicImageLinearViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/RestaurantNameID"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantDataLinearViewID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RestaurantPicImageLinearViewID" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RestaurantNameID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RestaurantDataLinearViewID"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**What i am trying to do** ::

I want to post the image and the text data shown in the snapshot to the server

---

**My research**::

I use the below code to post the data to server when listview is not involved

*Code i use for posting data*:

```
public void postImageData() {


        try
        {

            Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://54.218.73.244:7004/Details/");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg");
                reqEntity.addPart("key", bab);
                reqEntity.addPart("key1", new StringBody(name.getText().toString()));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
                reqEntity.addPart("picture", new StringBody(""));
            }
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

**note**:: URl i want to post the data is also `http://54.218.73.244:7004/Details/` and key value pair is also same as i have mentioned above in code

---

**My problem**::

I am having difficulty in posting data in a loop one after other since listview is involved

---

How can i resolve this

---

### {Edit}-2

```
public class ListOfContacts extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "rank";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    EditText mEditText;

    Button bTn;

    ImageView IV;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        bTn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.List_view_button_id);

        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        bTn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            }
        });


    }


    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListOfContacts.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fetching the information");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            postImageData();


            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7004/DescriptionSortedPrice/");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put(ListOfContacts.NAME, jsonobject.getString("Person_Name"));
                    map.put(ListOfContacts.FLAG, "http://54.218.73.244:7004/"+jsonobject.getString("Image_Name"));



                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(ListOfContacts.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


    public void postImageData() {


        try
        {

            Bitmap bitmapOrg = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://54.218.73.244:7004/Details/");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            try{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapOrg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image.jpg");
                reqEntity.addPart("key", bab);
                reqEntity.addPart("key1", new StringBody(name.getText().toString()));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
                reqEntity.addPart("picture", new StringBody(""));
            }
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am having difficulty in posting data in a loop one after other since
>   listview is involved

=> I can't assume and not sure what kind of difficulty you are facing. But I assume you would want to post all the items data to server.

If this is the case, then follow the below steps:

1. Create a main AsyncTask
2. Inside background, write a loop and iterate it through all the items and call the `postImageData()` function for each iteration.

P.S. this is not a standard and good solution for posting large data but you can create a Post data service so it won't prevent user to play with apps while uploading is being executed.

Comment: Thanks for your ... How to make a Post Data Service ? ... any good Stackoverflow link for a newbie like me to learn ... just to get started

Comment: @smriti3 if you are newbie then try the AsyncTask posting solution as I have mentioned. Later you could learn about creating a `service`.

Comment: Please look at the edit .... I followed your instructions ..... i created another Async task UploadDataFromListView .... but how to filll doIn background () ....i mean what i need to specify the size of the loop... i am confused there .... can u you give a edit to your answer to that section .... or should i need to make that async task in adapter for listview(listviewAdapter.java) ?

Comment: @smriti3 in this case, you don't need to create a new AsyncTask but instead write the post image code inside doInBackground() method of DownloadJSON task itself, i.e. after preparing arraylist.